# Count the search word in a dataframe per row

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dataframe in python

```
word    string                                               count    wordSummary
apple    One apple price is 40
apple    one apple price is 50 and three apples price are 60 but apple....
```

I want to count the exact word from the string and the 5char before and 5chars after the word

```
word    string                                                         count  wordSummary 
apple    One apple price is 40                                            1   Once apple price
apple    one apple price is 50 and three apples price are 60 but apple    2  one apple price
```

I tried the following part but shows error.

`df["count"] = df["string"].count(df["word"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try apply:

```
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['string'].lower().split(' ').count(row['word'].lower()), axis=1)
```

Comment: but it doesnt give me exact match, for example  it counts apples.

Comment: Just changed the code, see if that is what you wanted.

Comment: You mean case insensitive?

Comment: I changed the code to be case insensitive now, just put everything to lower case

Comment: Can you help me with the word summary part?

Comment: It is better to make another question in the forum.

Comment: If I want to search "apple pie" it will not give me proper result but if I remove the split() then it will give the result but will not give exact match.

Comment: Yes, because apple pie is not a word, you can't have a white space in it